# ListView grouping - missing text (WPF, c#, XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I'm trying display ListView grouping. I did as below:

ListView.xaml.**cs**

```
    ListViewModel lvm = new ListViewModel();
    lvUsers3.ItemsSource = lvm.getData();
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers3.ItemsSource);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Type");
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

ListView.**xaml**

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers3" Margin="0,197,94,0" ItemsSource="{Binding tvq}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Normal" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

ListViewModel.**cs**

```
namespace LayoutMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class ListViewModel
    {

        public List<test_view> getData()
        {
        testViewClassDataContext tv = new testViewClassDataContext();
        List<test_view> tvq = (from tt in tv.test_views
                               select tt).ToList();

            return tvq;
        }        

    }
}
```

On result I see that is grouped but the "type" value is missing (like was hidden?)

[image]

Comment: The code of your ListViewModel would be helpfull.

Comment: I have added the ListViewModel.cs

Comment: you're misunderstanding the way it works, you need to bind to the group not the group expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have applied the grouping you have created a group object that contains your sub items and this is what you are binding your group header to

the group object doesn't contain a Type property to bind to

try `"{Binding Name}"` instead of `"{Binding Type}"`